# How do I fill my 2D array with a string ? Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am using Arrays.fill() for integers but i dont know how to fill with string.
I want it to look like this on the terminal screen:

A A A

A A A

A A A

Comment: What did you try so far? How did you do it for a 2D `int` array?

Comment: int m, n;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        m = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] ar = new int[m][n];
        for (int[] row : ar)
            Arrays.fill(row, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++) { 
                System.out.print(ar[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate solution I can think of is using Java Streams.

```
String[][] table = new String[3][3];
Arrays.stream(table).forEach(strings -> Arrays.fill(strings,"A"));
```

It will give you output

```
[A, A, A]
[A, A, A]
[A, A, A]
```

To Print You can use

```
Arrays.stream(table).forEach(strings -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)));
```

Comment: "To Print" or `Arrays.stream(table).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println)`.